# Get file path from Uri created via FileProvider

Tags: android, uri, android-fileprovider

I use this method for getting file path from Uri https://github.com/iPaulPro/aFileChooser/blob/master/aFileChooser/src/com/ipaulpro/afilechooser/utils/FileUtils.java#L257

But it throw exception ("_data" column not found) when I pass Uri created such as below:

```
public static Uri uriFromFile(Context context, String path) {
    if (path == null) return null;
    return FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", new File(path));
}
```

I just need pass file path between my activities..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I use this method for getting file path from Uri

That is an unreliable approach that only works for a small number of `Uri` values.

> But it throw exception ("_data" column not found) when I pass Uri created such as below:

Of course. That code will fail for most sources of `Uri` values.

> Get file path from Uri created via FileProvider

In this specific case, you already know the "file path". It is represented by the variable named `path` in your code snippet.

More generally, you cannot get a "file path" for a `Uri`, for the simple reason that there is no requirement that a `Uri` point to a file, let alone one that you can access. Use `ContentResolver` and methods like `openInputStream()` to access the content represented by the `Uri`.

Comment: @user27799: `FileProvider` is only useful for delivering content *to other apps*. If you are not doing that, get rid of `FileProvider`. If your concern is the `FileUriExposedException`, do not put a `Uri` in the `Intent`, but instead put a `String` extra that contains the file path (e.g., `path.getAbsolutePath()`), or pass the `File` object itself as a `Serializable` extra. One or both of those should avoid the `FileUriExposedException`.